# "Specifier" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following passage is from [East Midland Trains](http://www.forbo.com/flooring/en-aa/inspiration-references/references/east-midlands-trains/rrlc97?segmentId=4715040e-5dfc-4cc7-b793-61b8a27529f3&categoryId=&countryId=) by Forbo Flooring Systems".

> There can be few environments more challenging for floor coverings than the inside of a busy saloon carriage. **Specifiers** involved in the interior fit out of new and refurbished rolling stock have to be confident that their chosen products have the exceptional level of durability required to maintain appearances and performance, despite punishment from intensive foot traffic, heavy wheeled luggage and trolleys, and the rigorous cleaning regimes imposed in passenger transport environments.

What does "**specifier**" mean in this context?

Comment: People who write the specifications and statements-of-work that form the meat of contracts.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, ***specifiers*** are the people *specifying* the floor coverings and other interior products for passenger rail cars.  To break it down:

> **Specifiers** [who are] involved in the interior fit out of (new and refurbished rolling stock) (aka train cars) have to be confident that their chosen products... [are really durable].

A *[specifier](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specifier)* is one who specifies.

> ***[specify](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specify)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Identify clearly and definitely.
>       *‘the coup leader promised an election but did not specify a date’*
>
>    1.1 *[with clause]* State a fact or requirement clearly and precisely.
>       *‘the agency failed to specify that the workers were not their employees’*
>
>    1.2  Include in an architect's or engineer's specifications.
>       *‘naval architects specified circular portholes’*